# How to rigorously prove that 1/t does not have a Laplace Transformation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I know that $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ does not have a Laplace transformation but I don't know the right(formal) way to prove it.

Here is my way:

Using the fact:

$L[\frac{f(t)}{t}]=\int_{s}^{\infty}F(t)dt$,

I have:

$L[\frac{1}{t}]=\int_{s}^{\infty}\frac{1}{s}dt = \frac{1}{s}|^{\infty}_{s}$

this is divergent and therefore the Laplace transformation of $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ does not exist.

However, I think my way is not rigorous. I hope I can receive a explicit proof of it (Maybe by definition to integrate).

Thank you so much!

---

Edit:

Actually, I do not know how to actually prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\frac{1}{t}dt$ diverges. Please help me with this!

Comment: Notice that $1/s$ is the Laplace transform of the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).  If you wish to shift the jump in this function to $s$ (where your integral starts), you would have an integrand of $\frac{1}{s}\mathrm{e}^{- s^2}$, not just $1/s$.

Comment: the definition of the Laplace transform is $L[f(t)] = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$. And $L[\frac{1}{t}] = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}e^{-st}dt$ diverges for every $s$

Comment: @EricTowers your 1st comment is impossible to understand. And the (bilateral) Laplace transform of $\frac{1_{t >\ -1}}{t}$ exists in the sense of distribution or principal value

Comment: @user1952009 : The function whose Laplace transform is $1/s$ is not $1$, it is the unit step function (with step at $0$).  This is unambiguously not a bilateral Laplace transform.  It is also not the unilateral Laplace transform unless $s=0$, which causes problems in OP's second display.  It is therefore, one of the relatively common variants that allow imprecisely specified integration on the interval $[s,\infty)$ for some $s>0$.  However, this means that OP's "$1$" is not the constant function $1$, but is the unit step function with step at $s$, which Laplace transform is the one I give.

Comment: Re: your edit:  Can you show that the part of the integral over $[0,1]$ diverges?

Comment: @EricTowers what you write is impossible to understand. $1/t$ is completely different to $1/s$, since $s$ is complex and it would be $f(t) = \frac{1}{\sigma+i t}$ whose (unilateral) Laplace transform is well-defined for $\sigma \ne 0$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46449/discussion-between-eric-towers-and-user1952009).

Comment: @Elmo write that $e^{-st} = 1+ (e^{-st}-1)$ and $|e^{-st}-1| < 2|s|t$ as $t \to 0$, therefore $\int_0^1 (e^{-st}-1) \frac{1}{t}dt$ converges, and $\int_0^1 e^{-st} \frac{1}{t}dt = \color{red}{\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t}dt }+\int_0^1 (e^{-st}-1) \frac{1}{t}dt$

Comment: @user1952009 : If you have an Answer, there is a perfectly good box, labelled "Your Answer", to contain it.  [Comments are not for answers.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments)

Comment: @EricTowers you are funny. The problem is that what Elmo wrote is impossible to understand (things like $\int_s^\infty F(t)dt$)

Comment: @user1952009 : Incorrect.  What Elmo wrote is entirely common in engineering and other sciences.  That you are not familiar with those uses does not automatically invalidate them.

Comment: @user1952009 : In fact, the transform pair you are calling out has a name in the literature.  It is "frequency domain integration".  It's line 7 in the table of pairs [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms).

Comment: I don't see what you mean, at all. And tks I know all my Fourier transforms

Comment: @user1952009 : Evidently not.

Comment: @EricTowers ?? ${}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We show that $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-st} \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t$ diverges.  Since this integrand is everywhere positive, it is sufficient to show that $\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{-st} \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t$ diverges.  Note that for $t \in [0,1]$ and $s \geq 0$, $\mathrm{e}^{st} \leq \mathrm{e}^{s}$ and so $\mathrm{e}^{-st} \geq \mathrm{e}^{-s}$.  Consequently, 
$$\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{-st} \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t \geq \int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{-s} \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t = \mathrm{e}^{-s}\int_0^1  \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t  \text{,}  $$ 
and we recognize this latter integral as one which diverges to infinity.  Therefore, the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{t}$ (with respect to $t$) does not exist.

Comment: Or just apply limit comparison: $$\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{e^{st}/t}{1/t} = 1$$